# how to extract bold words and normal text separately from text document using apache tika

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

i am using apache tika for parsing word document.but it is extracting whole content and i want to extract header separately and normal text seperately.here is the code i am trying.

```
    public class TextParser 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,SAXException, 
    TikaException {

      //detecting the file type
      BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
     // System.out.println("output"+handler.toString());
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\TikaExamples\\example.txt"));
      ParseContext pcontext=new ParseContext();

      //Text document parser
      TXTParser  textParser = new TXTParser();
      textParser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);
      System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());
      System.out.println("Metadata of the document:");
      String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

      for(String name : metadataNames) {
         System.out.println(name + " : " + metadata.get(name));
      }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Fetch as HTML rather than Plain Text then process the HTML? http://tika.apache.org/1.15/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML

Comment: i fetched in html form . how to process it now

Comment: i want to write it into xlsx file